# Minimizing $f(x) = \frac 14 (x^T A x)^2 + b^T x$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus, cubics

I have the following function

$$f(x) = \frac 14 (x^T A x)^2 + b^T x$$

where $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, and I proved its convexity. However, when I try to minimize it, I get stuck. After I take its gradient w.r.t. vector $x$ and equate it to $0$

$$A x x^T A x = -b$$

I can't find a way to move both $A$'s to the right hand side of the equation. What trick should I use to move them? The rest is straightforward: just a bunch of norm and normalized vector stuff. Thanks.

Comment: What if you assume that $x=\alpha A^{-1}b$ for some scalar $\alpha$. Feeding this back in then gives you a simple equation for  $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I think Mr. Grant's solution is similar to yours!

Answer (score 3):

The correct optimality condition is
$$(x^TAx)Ax + b = 0$$
Since $A$ is positive definite, $(x^TAx)Ax$ will be zero if and only if $x=0$. Therefore, the only way $x=0$ can be the solution is if $b=0$ as well. On the other hand, if $b\neq 0$, then $x\neq 0$, and
$$x = -(x^TAx)^{-1} A^{-1} b$$
At first this may not seem helpful, but it helps reveal an important point: since $x^TAx$ is a scalar,
$$x = \lambda A^{-1} b$$
for *some* value of $\lambda$. (Indeed, we didn't need to assume $x\neq 0$ to see this.) Let's plug that into the original optimality conditions; we get
$$\lambda^3(b^TA^{-1}b)b + b = \left(\lambda^3(b^TA^{-1}b) + 1\right) b = 0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \lambda = -(b^TA^{-1}b)^{-1/3}$$
Therefore,
$$x = -(b^TA^{-1}b)^{-1/3} A^{-1} b$$

Comment: Oh yeah. In my problem the vector x cannot be equal to 0. Sorry for that. I forgot to mention that constraint. Oh very lovely solution. Thank you Mr. Grant!

Comment: That simplifies things even further then!

Comment: Yes, that’s right.